# How to change every letter in a word using dictionary?

Tags: kotlin

So basically the title I want to change the word letters to another word but it says I have to specify the parameter

```
fun main() {
    val dictionary = mapOf( "c" to "b", "a" to "d" , "r" to "e"//here is the letters i want to change
        )
    val letters = "car"//the word i want to change
    
    for (me in letters){

        println(dictionary[me])


    }
}
```

i want for "car" to be "bde"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your map has *strings* as keys, because you used string literals in these places:

```
val dictionary = mapOf( "c" to "b", "a" to "d" , "r" to "e")
                        ***         ***          ***
```

However, when you access the map, you are accessing it using `me`, which is a `Char` you got from the string `letters`. This causes the error.

I would suggest that you change the map to use `Char` keys instead. Change the string literals to character literals:

```
val dictionary = mapOf( 'c' to "b", 'a' to "d" , 'r' to "e")
                        ***         ***          ***
```

Notice that the letters are now surrounded with single quotes.

Though it is not required to solve this particular problem, you can also change the map's values to character literals too.

After that, you should use `print` instead of `println` to print the map values out, so that they are all printed on the same line:

```
for (me in letters){
    print(dictionary[me] ?: me.toString())
}
```

Note that I added the `?: me.toString()` part so that if no replacement was found in the map, the original letter would be printed.

If you want a single string as the result, rather than having it printed out,

```
val result = letters.map { dictionary[it] ?: it.toString() }.joinToString("")
```